# UIPopoverController Direction

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, uipopovercontroller

I want to know how to create a popover hint message that would not appear on top of the UIButton but on the left/right side of it. Something like in this picture:
[image]

With a nice popup/slide animation. Is there a simple way to do it? Or a library that can handle such things?

Comment: re you sure you want a `UIPopoverController`? If yes, simply using  `Right`  `UIPopoverArrowDirection` should do the job.. however if you want some custom UI or animation and want to show multiple views like this.. you better start looking for a custom component. Also, edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure if I want a UIPopoverController... I'm searching for the best possible solution at the moment... My first guess was that UIPopoverController would do the job...

Comment: You can try and use `UIPopoverController` with `UIPopoverArrowDirection` `Right` or `Left`

Comment: @lukya The UIPopoverController works but now 2 things: 
1. How to add animation when appearing? It disappears nicely but there is no animation on the "appear" part, it just pop ups. I have animated set to YES.
2. How to add text to the UIPopoverController? At the moment I have a empty "cloud".